# Android ClassNotFound with multidex

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I've a big project with 10 external modules. Obviously I've enabled multidex because the total of the methods is over 100k.

Now, if I add "facebook-android" dependency at the project, I've some error ClassNotFound when I start my app. Seems that the class was not loaded into `classes.dex`. If I remove this dependency, all works correctly.

Precisely I've this error:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

Comment: Please add a full exception stack trace and your `build.gradle`'s dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you enable multidex. Once your application start, application will load all other dexes. I post some code bellow.

```
 public static void install(Context context) {
    Log.i("MultiDex", "install");
    if(IS_VM_MULTIDEX_CAPABLE) {
        Log.i("MultiDex", "VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.");
    } else if(VERSION.SDK_INT < 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Multi dex installation failed. SDK " + VERSION.SDK_INT + " is unsupported. Min SDK version is " + 4 + ".");
    }
```

So

1. **First check your logcat to see if MultiDex meets error.**
2. **If there is no error found. Check your APK, find out if
   *org.slf4j.LoggerFactory* builded in your APK's dex files.**